# In-the-wild accuracy of mobile device wall clock

Tags: android, ios, web-applications, real-time-clock

I like to sync some events between fixed and mobile devices to at about video frame precision (eg. 1/30s).

Mobile device application will be a web application (eg. running in Chrome or Safari most likely on Android or iOS platform for the vast majority of users).

Question is, if using "wall clock" on all those devices is maybe better then network-based syncing over the available protocols (eg. WebSocket).
My bet is that some short-running time syncing on low reliability mobile network connections will stand short against the well synchronized device clocks (using the mobile carrier, GPS and NTP as I imagine).